# How to use C code variable inside system()

Tags: c, sed, printf

I am using C code with sed. I want to read lines in the interval 1-10,11-20 etc. to perform some calculation.

```
int i,j,m,n;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   j=i+1;
   //correction. m,n is modified which was incorrect earlier.
   m=i*10;
   n=j*10;
   system("sed -n 'm,n p' oldfile > newfile");
   }
```

Ouput.

```
  m,n p
```

It looks the variable is not passed in system. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I am not much used to `sed` but is the command working fine when you do the same on shell?

Comment: if you want to redirect output to a file, better store the path using `sprintf` along with the command and use it.

Comment: there is no `$<variable>` replacement in C.

Comment: Interesting we all used `100` for size of buffer

Comment: "100 bytes should be enough for anyone" :)

Comment: @IrAM my mistake, it has to be m,n p, with m=i*10; n=j*10 which is supposed to come from C code.

Comment: Study string handling chapter in your C programming book.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be using `m = 10 * i + 1; n = 10 * (i + 1);` to get ranges 1-10 for `i = 0`, 11-20 for `i = 1`, etc. (and `j` becomes irrelevant).  Your code generates 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, etc. which is quite different, not least because 0 is not necessarily acceptable to `sed` and the ranges overlap.

Comment: Calling `sed` inside `C` is similar to having an entire arsenal of tools available, but selecting the sledgehammer to paint a wall. Could you just not read the file line-by line, and when you reach the lines of interest, store the 10 lines in a buffer and post-process the buffer for the computations.

Comment: Using `system` for starting sub-processes may be insecure. If you need external tools to do a task, consider using `fork`/`exec`/`waitpid` rather than `system`. This will not only be safer, but will also be more flexible, give you async, better error detection, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to build the command line:

```
char cmdline[100];
sprintf(cmdline, "sed -n '%d,%dp'  oldfile.txt > newfile.txt", 10*i+1, 10*(i+1));
puts(cmdline); // optionally, verify manually it's going to do the right thing
system(cmdline);
```

(This is vulnerable to buffer overflow, but if your command-line arguments are not too flexible, 100 bytes should be enough.)

Comment: Running code created by string manipulations may have bigger issues than buffer overflow. It looks OK in this case though, this is just meant as  a warning to other readers. Especially SQL users.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot replace part of a string literal in C. What you need is to

- Form a string with patterns
- Replace those patterns with proper values with formatted I/O functions.

[`sprintf()/snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) will be your friend in this. You can do something like (copying from pmg's comment)

```
char cmd[100]; 
snprintf(cmd, 100, "sed -n '%d,%dp'  oldfile > newfile", 10*i+1, 10*(i+1)); 
system(cmd);
```